# TypeScript type for React Router's Route's path?

Tags: typescript, react-router

I'm using React Router with TypeScript. How can I use an `enum` for the `path` prop?

```
enum paths = "page-1" | "page-2"

interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<MatchParams> {}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/page-1">
        <Page1 />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/page-2">
        <Page2 />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use String enums!

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums

```html
enum paths = {
  page1= "page-1"
  page2= "page-2"
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={paths.page1}>
        <Page1 />
      </Route>
      <Route path={paths.page2}>
        <Page2 />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  )
```

Comment: simple enough solution!